# Where do Great Musicians go?

Tags: civilization-6

I've gotten my great musicians to go to certain wonders, but not sure where else to put them. My theater districts accept artists, writers, and artifacts (depending on art gallery vs arch museum). Where do I put them? And how do I do a tour? Do I just put them to another civ's building that I would drop them on usually? I do have open borders with a few folks right now.

Answer (score 2):

The way to place Great Musicians easily is way later in the game apparently with http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Broadcast_Center_(Civ6)